# How to get name of top baselayer

Tags: leaflet

I have a leaflet map with tile layers and a layer control [L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays)]. How can I get the name of the base layer that is currently shown in javascript?

Comment: You could hook the `baselayerchange` event on the control  which passes the newly active base layer.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to the `baselayerchange` event on your map instance, as mentioned in the [Leaflet Docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-baselayerchange):

> Fired when the base layer is changed through the layer control.

Here's an example to illustrate the possibilities:

```
map.on( 'baselayerchange', function (event) {
    console.log('Layer name -> ', event.name);
    console.log('Layer URL -> ', event.layer.options.url);
    console.log('Layer attribution -> ', event.layer.options.attribution);
});
```

It's been a while since this questions was asked, but I hope that it can still be useful to somebody out there :)